# Prove reduction formula

Tags: integration

If $∫_0^{π/2} \cos ^nxdx=I_n$, prove that $nI_n=\left(n-1\right)I_{n-2}, \left(n>1\right)$

I took $\cos ^nx$ as $\cos ^{n-2}x\cos ^2x$ and replaced $\cos ^2x$ with $1-\sin ^2x$. Then integrated using by parts. Could not arrive at the given result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use $\cos    xdx = d\left(\sin    x\right)$ :
$$\eqalign{
  & I_n = ∫_0^{{π  \over 2}} {{{\cos  }^n}x} dx = ∫_0^{{π  \over 2}} {{{\cos  }^{n - 1}}x} d\left(\sin  x\right)  \cr 
  &  = \left. {\sin  x{{\cos  }^{n - 1}}x} \right|_0^{{π  \over 2}} + \left(n - 1\right)∫_0^{{π  \over 2}} {{{\sin  }^2}x{{\cos  }^{n - 2}}x} dx  \cr 
  &  = \left(n - 1\right)∫_0^{{π  \over 2}} {\left(1 - {{\cos  }^2}x\right){{\cos  }^{n - 2}}x} dx  \cr 
  &  = \left(n - 1\right){I_{n - 2}} - \left(n - 1\right){I_n} \cr
  &  \Longrightarrow n{I_n} = \left(n - 1\right){I_{n - 2}}
}$$

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of substitution. I have never used it before

Comment: @user140161 $d(f(x)) = f'(x)dx$

Comment: In the second line, did you use by parts?

Comment: @user140161 Of course. And note that $\left. {\sin x{{\cos }^{n - 1}}x} \right|_0^{{\pi  \over 2}} = 0$

Comment: @user140161 It is not a substitution. What shine did was, rewriting $cos^nx$ as $cos^{n-1}x$ times $cosx$ and on that product the formula of Integration by Parts is used.